# pthread_cancel does not kill commands child is running with popen (Linux with g++)

Tags: linux, g++, pthreads, system, popen

I have a C++ program that creates a thread and the thread runs a command that hangs forever using popen.

When the parent calls pthread_cancel, the thread gets cancelled but the hung command being run by the thread does not exit, it gets taken over by init.

```
//Main.cpp
void * runCmdFn (void *) {
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = popen("/root/hangup","r");
    pclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th,NULL,runCmdFn,NULL);
    sleep(30);
    pthread_cancel(th);
    return 0;
}
```

pstree output of running program :

```
pthread(39263)─┬─hangup(39265)
               └─{pthread}(39264)
```

After the parent exits hangup is taken over by init:

```
├─hangup(39265)
```

Is there a way i can spawn a thread which executes a system call (which gets hung after a while) and the parent can kill or cancel all of these ?

Comment: Quick note - asynchronous cancellation is meant for use in pure compute-bound loops, that don't call any system calls, and that do thus also inherently not include cancellation points. When enabled, you are not allowed to call any system calls except those that are marked as async-cancel-safe - and there are only three of those: `pthread_cancel()`, `pthread_setcancelstate()`, and `pthread_setcanceltype()`. See section 2.9.5 on Thread Cancellation here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html

Comment: I changed my implementation to using fork that helped. I fork a process instead of a thread. And child  process sets the prctl parameter to say kill when parent dies :
        
  if ( pid == 0 ) {
     ::prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL);
     // execute my command that hangs up 
  }